# bytearray.fromhex doesn't convert when Alphabates (A,B,C,D,E,F)are present in number

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to convert a text file data (which is encoded in ANSI) in hex value using

`line = bytearray.fromhex(x)`

But it shows the below error.

> line = bytearray.fromhex(x)  ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found
>   in fromhex() arg at position 5

How can I achieve the correct conversion? Please provide me a solution.

Comment: Encoding = 'ANSI' ; so it does not go beyond the 127 (7F), How can I convert the value above 7F in Hex.

Answer (score -1):

You have to encode the text to hex format first. You can use the `encode` function for this.

> The method encode() returns an encoded version of the string. Default encoding is the current default string encoding. The errors may be given to set a different error handling scheme.

Try this:

```
line = bytearray.fromhex(x.encode("hex"))
```

**EDIT:**

For Python 3.4 and higher, you need to go via the codecs module and the hex_codec codec:

```
line = bytearray.fromhex(codecs.encode(x, 'hex_codec'))
```

Comment: line=bytearray.fromhex (x.encode ("hex"))
LookupError: 'hex' is not a text encoding; use codecs.encode() to handle arbitrary codecs, here "hex" is what?

Comment: @TarangJain Please see my edited answer for Python versions 3.4 and higher.

Comment: @TarangJain Were you able to solve the problem using the above-mentioned solution?

Comment: for number in P[:-1]:
    row = bytearray.fromhex(codecs.encode(number, 'hex_codec')
#    print(row)
    ID = struct.unpack(struct_fmt, row)
    print(ID)
    IDname.append(ID)

Comment: What is the format, i.e., `struct_fmt` you are using?

Comment: Try `row = bytearray.fromhex(codecs.encode(bytes(number,'ascii'), 'hex_codec').decode())`.

Comment: struct_fmt = '<BBBHI33H33

Comment: in place of 'ascii' , I need to use 'ANSI'

Comment: There's no ansi encoding in Python Standard Encodings.
Choose appropriate encodings from following link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings